# Get object index in NSMutableArray using dictionary object key in iphone sdk

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

i'm trying to get object index from array using dictionary key object... but unable to get it.

Here are the details..

I have the Array having dictionaries....

```
 (
   {
        CATEGORYID = 865;
        CATEGORYNAME = "sample1";
        CATEGORYTHUMBIMAGEURL = "1.jpg";
    },
            {
        CATEGORYID = 140;
        CATEGORYNAME = "sample2";
        CATEGORYTHUMBIMAGEURL = "2.jpg";
    },
            {
        CATEGORYID = 1194;
        CATEGORYNAME = "sample3";
        CATEGORYTHUMBIMAGEURL = "3.jpg";
    }
);
```

Here i have the CATEGORYID.... using category id i need to get the object index at array...

The code i have implemented was...

```
 int inx;
    for (int i=0; i<[mutArrData count]; i++) {
    NSString *str=(NSString*)[sender tag];
    //NSLog(@"MY Str %@",str);
    id myOjbect =(id)[sender tag];
    //NSLog(@"My OBJECT %d",[myOjbect intValue]);

    if ([[[mutArrData objectAtIndex:i] allKeys] containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sender tag]]]) {
        inx=i;
        NSLog(@"Breaking here %d",inx);

    }

}
```

But unable to get it, can any one help...

Answer (score 1):

One side issue is that tag is an integer, and above you treat it as a NSString, an object and an integer.

Assuming you listed your array as some sample data, your main issue though is that allKeys is returning you an array of *key names* and not the values you want to compare.

What you want to do is pull out the int value for the categoryid key:

```
// Return matching index, or -1 for not found
-(int)indexInArray:(NSArray)array forCategoryId:(int)categoryId {
  for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    int currentCategoryId = [[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"CATEGORYID"] integerValue];
    if (currentCategoryId == categoryId) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```